# Laravel 5.4 : Translate routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

is there a simple way to translate my routes in Laravel 5.4. My translation files located in here:

```
/resources
    /lang
        /en
            routes.php
        /de
            routes.php
```

In my web.php i define my routes like this:

```
Route::get('/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);

    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('{locale}/contact', 'ContactController@index');
```

I have found very elaborate solutions or solutions for Laravel 4. I am sure that Laravel has also provided a simple solution. Can someone explain to me the best approach?

Thanks.

Comment: try this one https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/example-on-how-to-use-multiple-locales-in-your-laravel-5-website

Comment: I will test it - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

we usually do it like this

to get the current language:

```
$request = request()->segment(1);
$language = null;
if (!empty($request) && in_array($request,config('translatable.locales'))) {
  $language = $request;
  App::setLocale($language);
} else {
    $language = 'nl';
}
```

routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => $language], function () {
    Route::get(trans('routes.newsletter'), array('as' => 'newsletter.index', 'uses' => 'NewsletterController@index'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a file translatable.php in my config folder:

```
<?php

return [

    'locales' => ['en', 'de'],

];
```

web.php:

```
$request = request()->segment(1);
$language = null;

if (!empty($request) && in_array($request,config('translatable.locales'))) {
    $language = $request;
    App::setLocale($language);
} else {
    $language = 'de';
}

Route::get('/', function() {
    return redirect()->action('WelcomeController@index');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => $language], function () {

    /*
    Route::get('/', function(){
        return View::make('welcome');
    });
    */

    Route::get('/',
        array(  'as'      => 'welcome.index',
                'uses'    => 'WelcomeController@index'));


    Route::get(trans('routes.contact'),
        array('as'      => 'contact.index',
              'uses'    => 'ContactController@index'));

});
```

Works fine - Thanks. Is the redirect also the best practice?
Best regards